# iphone uibutton with square corners

Tags: iphone, uibutton

How can I create UIButton in iphone app programatically to have square corners.
I don't want to have rounded corners.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set it's buttonType to UIButtonTypeCustom so it doesn't draw the rounded rect, then give the UIButton's layer a border:

```
//you need this import
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

[button.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[button.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

take a custom button and change its background color.

The button will be having squared corners or the other alternate is set image as background to the button. You can choose whatever you like as per your requirement.

Happy Coding...